# Spellchecking in PHP

Tags: php, spell-checking

I am looking to possibly add in some sort of spellchecking/correction in PHP, is there anything that is recommended?

Is this a slow process?  It would be for user submitted blog posts and forum post, possibly even just be used in an admin area if performance is not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [Pspell](http://au.php.net/pspell) libraries in PHP, but also don't forget that most modern browsers these days come with a built-in spell checker which would be:

1. A lot more intuitive to the user (works just like Word and every other desktop app)
2. Able to be extended with the user adding words to their own dictionaries
3. A heck of a lot less work for you.

The performance I don't think would be an issue, it's just that you'd have to make your own interface for getting the user to select the correct spelling for every misspelt word, etc.

Comment: good points, I almost just wanna do it for fun, not production

Answer (score 1):

[tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) has a [spellchecker plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/spellchecker) that works with Google's free spellchecking service. Fairly easy to setup and doesn't have any server-side dependencies other than the openssl extension for PHP and possibly curl. I prefer this because it doesn't involving installing any other server-side libraries like Pspell.

Check out the plugin in action on the [examples](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php) and [tinyMCE download](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php) page for a copy of the spellchecker plugin. (I'm not sure if the spellcheck on the example page is using Google or a server-side library like pspell, but the behavior is identical).